# target string after second <br> jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I would like to target a string after second `<br>` and then perform an action to find out if this string contains any number. If not then alert. My action code is working but I need the first part. To targer precisely string after second `<br>`

html

```
<div class="xxx">aaa
<br>
text
<br>
text123
<br>
text
<br>
</div>
```

jquery

```
var val = $(".xxx").html();
var matches = val.match(/\d+/g);
if (matches == null) {
alert('number');
}
```

edit: i need to use jquery 1.3.2

Comment: `$('.xxx').html().split('<br>')[2].match(/\d+/g)`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zaCZ7/

Comment: this works. thank you. how can I vote for best answer in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Find the second `br` element and get the next sibling:

```
var val = $('.xxx > br').get(1).nextSibling.nodeValue;
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/R4xz7)

Comment: And the `.nextSibling` and `.nodeValue`, how standard are those?

Comment: They are part of DOM Level 1 (http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-core.html). Should be super standard ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could select the text node that corresponds to the one after the second BR tag like so:

```
$thirdText = $(".xxx").contents().eq(4); //select the 5th node
```

And here's a demo for you: http://jsfiddle.net/ptvNP/

This requires your code to be in a certain format though: TEXT, BR, TEXT, BR, TEXT

This may not be ideal for you, but the underlying method of using `.contents()` to reach the text nodes is my main point.